# tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve missing args

Tags: c, ebpf, kprobe, cilium, tracepoint

I use [cilium-ebpf](https://github.com/cilium/ebpf) to write some simple monitoring programs. Currently I want to use `tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve` to get argv. but I am having problems with missing arguments.

The following is an example of code that can be reproduced:

task.c

```c
//go:build ignore

#include "common.h"
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

struct execve {
    __u64 unused;
    __u32 nr;
    const char *filename;
    const char *const *argv;
    const char *const *envp;
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int sys_enter_execve(struct execve *ctx) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const char *arg = NULL;
        bpf_probe_read_user(&arg, sizeof(arg), &ctx->argv[i]);
        bpf_printk("arg%d: %s ", i, arg);
    }
    bpf_printk("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/cilium/ebpf/link"
    "github.com/cilium/ebpf/rlimit"
    "log"
    "time"
)

//go:generate go run github.com/cilium/ebpf/cmd/bpf2go bpf task.c -- -I../
func main() {

    // Allow the current process to lock memory for eBPF resources.
    if err := rlimit.RemoveMemlock(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    objs := bpfObjects{}
    if err := loadBpfObjects(&objs, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("loading objects: %v", err)
    }
    defer objs.Close()

    tpExecve, err := link.Tracepoint("syscalls", "sys_enter_execve", objs.SysEnterExecve, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer tpExecve.Close()

    // Wait for signals.
    log.Printf("waiting for signals")

    // Read loop reporting the total amount of times the kernel
    // function was entered, once per second.
    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for range ticker.C {
        log.Printf("tick \n")
    }
}
```

You can see that in `task.c` I tried to use `tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve` to get the argv and print them out.

After getting this ebpf program up and running, I will use ssh on another server to execute a script remotely. The command to be executed on the other server is shown below:

```bash
// hc is the server that run the ebpf program
ssh hc "see_app=be2e4d3d-2dad-4e48-a867-3006433f7e59;sh ./test.sh"
```

Ideally, the output of bpf_trace_printk should look like this:

```
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233432: bpf_trace_printk: arg0: bash
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233441: bpf_trace_printk: arg1: -c
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233448: bpf_trace_printk: arg2: see_app=be2e4d3d-2dad-4e48-a867-3006433f7e59;sh ./test.sh
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233460: bpf_trace_printk: arg3:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233465: bpf_trace_printk: arg4:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233469: bpf_trace_printk: arg5:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233473: bpf_trace_printk: arg6:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233477: bpf_trace_printk: arg7:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233486: bpf_trace_printk: arg8:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233495: bpf_trace_printk: arg9:
sh-2127037 [001] d..31 763364.233497: bpf_trace_printk:
```

But in sometime, the `-c` parameter is lost:

```
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999571: bpf_trace_printk: arg0: bash
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999582: bpf_trace_printk: arg1:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999589: bpf_trace_printk: arg2: see_app=be2e4d3d-2dad-4e48-a867-3006433f7e59;sh ./test.sh
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999597: bpf_trace_printk: arg3:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999600: bpf_trace_printk: arg4:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999604: bpf_trace_printk: arg5:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999607: bpf_trace_printk: arg6:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999611: bpf_trace_printk: arg7:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999618: bpf_trace_printk: arg8:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999625: bpf_trace_printk: arg9:
sh-2128777 [001] d..31 763441.999626: bpf_trace_printk:
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and solved it?

I also tried using kprobe/sys_execve, but I still have the problem of missing parameters

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should check result of bpf_probe_read_user, also you may add logging the pointer values using %llx format specifier to find out what's the problem. But also, better to specify what's your kernel version and architecture.